# How do I play back the first my first song called in Android?

Tags: java, android, loops, android-mediaplayer, sensors

I am able to begin the first song, upon detecting movement, it will change to another song, however, if I stop movement, it does not begin the first song again. Should I loop it? Or is there something I am missing?

Here's my **MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.capisrem.manofsteel;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private MediaPlayer mp1, mp2;
    private float mAccel; // acceleration apart from gravity
    private float mAccelCurrent; // current acceleration including gravity
    private float mAccelLast; // last acceleration including gravity

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mAccel = 0.00f;
        mAccelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        mAccelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

        // Intro
        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.intro);
        // Add OnCompletionListener to release the
        mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp1) {
                mp1.start();
            }

        });

        // Saving the World!
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.savingtheworld);
    }

    private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {

            float x = se.values[0];
            float y = se.values[1];
            float z = se.values[2];
            mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
            mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x * x + y * y + z * z));
            float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
            mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter

            if (mAccel > 8) {
                if (mp1.isPlaying()) {
                    mp1.stop();
                }
                mp2.start();
            }

            mp1.start();

        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {

    float x = se.values[0];
    float y = se.values[1];
    float z = se.values[2];

    mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
    mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x * x + y * y + z * z));

    float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
    mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter

    if (mAccel > 8) {
        if (mp1.isPlaying()) {
            mp1.stop();
        }
        mp2.start();
    }
    m2.stop(); // **try to add this line**
    mp1.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried that, still nothing. The logcat in eclipse is looping a callback error but I'm not sure where or why it is going wrong. After the first song, it won't play the second. The first doesn't play again either if the shake stops.